# ElasticSearch 6.2: autocomplete search from MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, elasticsearch, logstash

First at all, I would like to say that I use Elasticsearch and Logstash 6.2 and due the big update, a lot of topics are not compatible. I looked twice before posting mine. :)

I use MySQL as database and with Logstash 6.2 and JDBC, I transfer automatically my rows in Elasticsearch 6.2. Everything works fine from this side !

However, I'm trying to use Elasticsearch as search engine in a Node/Express' project. I would like to create an autocomplete searchbar as describes in this tutorial [Leveraging the Power of Elasticsearch: Autocomplete and Fuzzy Search](https://blog.manifold.co/leveraging-the-power-of-elasticsearch-autocomplete-and-fuzzy-search-1d491d3e0b38).

The problem is I can't enable auto completion because my data loaded from MySQL are as String and not as Completion type:

> Illegal_argument_exception, reason:Field [extid] is not a completion suggest field, status:400

So for the *getSuggestions* function, I try this :

```
function getSuggestions(text, size){
   return elasticClient.search({
   index: indexName,
   type: indexType,
   body: {
       suggest: {
           extidSuggester: {
               text: text+'~',
               term: {
                   field: "extid",
                   size: size
               }
           },
           nameSuggester: {
               text: text+'~',
               term: {
                   field: "name",
                   size: size
               }
           }
         }
       }
  });
}
```

which does not give me autocompletion.

A solution could be to filter the targeted columns in the Logstash conf and force to the completion's type. Is someone know how to perform that ?

Is there another solution to resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally answer myself.

When I created the mapping, I used a default mapping found on [github](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template-es6x.json).

I added to this mapping the type *completion* for the needed fields and it resolved my issue.

Simple as that !